# In Python, how to subtract x-axis labels by a number without changing the input data

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

How can I subtract all x-axis values labeled on my plot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7h0v.png) by the minimum x-axis value so that they appear as 0, 2000, 7000, 9000 WITHOUT changing any values for Xa in the code?

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Xa=[-4000,-2000,3000,5000]
Ya=[5,6,7,8]
plt.plot(Xa, Ya, 'o')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the x-axis labels, you might as well change the x-value of your plot. The code below plots the desired output and Xa is not changed:

```
Xa=[-4000,-2000,3000,5000]
Ya=[5,6,7,8]
plt.plot(np.array(Xa)-np.min(Xa), Ya, 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output plot from the code above]

If you need the adjusted values in Xa to be in your x-axis ticks:

```
Xa=[-4000,-2000,3000,5000]
Ya=[5,6,7,8]
plt.plot(np.array(Xa)-np.min(Xa), Ya, 'o')
plt.xticks(np.array(Xa)-np.min(Xa))
plt.show()
```

[image: Output with x values in xticks]

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Xa=[-4000,-2000,3000,5000]
Ya=[5,6,7,8]
plt.plot([i - min(Xa) for i in Xa], Ya, 'o')
plt.show()
```

I am not sure what are you asking but these code must work. Please feel free to elaborate your question. Do you want to create another number system where Xa value Xa=[0,2000,5000,9000] is Xa=[-4000,-2000,3000,5000] in our current number system?
[image]

You can also use `plt.xticks([i - min(Xa) for i in Xa])` for matching x-axis tick marks at the exact place you need.

Comment: Thanks, however, I need the values for Xa to remain the same when putting them on the plot. I need instead to change the displayed values on the X-axis of the plot.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed later. Now this code must work. Also there is a another answer available to this as well. If none of these satisfy your query then feel free to comment again.